# Xaml component visible in multiple pages in Silverlight+XNA applications

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

I am doing a Silverlight+XNA game for windows phone 7 and I need to have a xaml animation which can appear in multiple pages. What is the best practice for doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by animation, and the way it is implemented, one of the most obvious ways would be putting it in a XAML `ResourceDictionary`, either through a separate XAML file, or part of the core `App.xaml`.

Comment: By animation I mean just an image that fades in/fades out.

Answer (score 0):

Making a user control would be a good way of going about it. Make a User Control with an image in it. Let the user control set the Image and run the animations.